# What should be more appropriate in the case? RowMapper or ResultSetExtractor?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have two DAO methods

```
public EUser getEUserById(Integer id) {
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate());
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("id", id);
    EUser e = (EUser) template.queryForObject(sql, params, new EUserRowMapper());
    return e;
}

public List<EUser> getEUsers() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    List<EUser> es = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new EUserRowMapper());
    return es;
}
```

`Row-mapper` itself:

```
private class EUserRowMapper implements RowMapper<EUser> {
    public EUser mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1)
            throws SQLException {
        EUser e = new EUser();
        e.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        e.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        //etc
        return e;
    }
}
```

But after I read the documenattion about these methods, I got doubted about my choice. What would be more appropriate to use here [ResultSetExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) or [RowMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html)?

Comment: Maybe you should post the "Logic".

Comment: @RC. No problem. Just a second.

Comment: @RC.  Could you look at my updated Q?

Comment: I think RowMapper is OK here. ResultSetExtractor is for some more complex cases. For eaxmple mapping objects with one to many relation.

Comment: @Evgeni Thanks, interesting. But why don't we use RowMapper in that case as well?

Comment: The row mapper gives you control over one row of the result set, while the ResultSetExtractor gives you the whole RS. Just more control and more options.

Comment: @Evgeni It's still a bit unclear. The `ResultSetExtractor` interface has the `extractData(ResultSet rs)`, meanwhile `RowMapper` has `mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1)`. Did you mean that `RowMapper` gives us the control to the particular row in cotrast to `ResultSetExtractor` which gives us control to the whole `ResultSet`?

Comment: @Evgeni So, it's preffered to use `RowMapper` in simple cases rather than `ResultSetExtractor`...

Comment: @user3663882 That is even explicitly mentioned in the API documentation you link to in your question.